# col-md-4 overlapping on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a contact section on the site, this section should contain columns, as the site is divided into 12 I used col-md-4, but in mobile it simply stands one on top of the other.

How are you doing.

[image: how are you doing]

And I'm trying to leave it this way.

[image: right]

**HTML**

```
  <section class="third-section">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 d-flex justify-content-start">
      <h4>Entre em contato com a gente:</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 phone">
      <div class="d-flex align-items-center resd">
        <p> 51 99999999</p>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex align-items-center"><img src="img/iconwpp.png" alt="icone whatsapp">
        <p>51 999999999</p>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex align-items-center"><img src="img/iconwpp.png" alt="icone whatsapp">
        <p>51 999999999</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 address">
      <p>Rua XXXXX</p>
      <p>XXXXXXXX/RS</p>
      <p>CEP xxxx-xxx</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.third-section{
 margin-top: 10%;
 margin-bottom: 5%;
 padding-left: 35%;
 padding-right: 30%;

 .phone{
 img{
 margin-right: 3px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 height: 20px;
}
.resd{
  margin-left: 23px;
}
 }
 h4{
 font-size: 1.6em;
 color: #77D3C2;
 }
 p{
 font-size: 1.2em;
 line-height: 1em;
 color: #999999
 }
 }
```

Comment: upload your relevant images on your example

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this would be to manually specify that each part should take up four columns on a smaller device, by adding `.col-sm-4` to each of the elements.

Note that this will, however, cause a horizontal overlap in your example due to having such a large amount of content in such a confined space. To rememedy this, I've changed the `.third-section` horizontal padding to only be `3%`, but you may want to accommodate for this in a different way in the actual layout.

```css
.third-section {
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  padding-left: 3%;
  padding-right: 3%;
  /*padding-left: 35%; */
  /* padding-right: 30%; */
}

.third-section .phone img {
  margin-right: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.third-section .phone .resd {
  margin-left: 23px;
}

.third-section h4 {
  font-size: 1.6em;
  color: #77D3C2;
}

.third-section p {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 1em;
  color: #999999;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<section class="third-section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 d-flex justify-content-start">
        <h4>Entre em contato com a gente:</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 phone">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center resd">
          <p> 51 99999999</p>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center"><img src="img/iconwpp.png" alt="icone whatsapp">
          <p>51 999999999</p>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center"><img src="img/iconwpp.png" alt="icone whatsapp">
          <p>51 999999999</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 address">
        <p>Rua XXXXX</p>
        <p>XXXXXXXX/RS</p>
        <p>CEP xxxx-xxx</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```